# Multiple nested IndexRoutes not registering

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have these files in a largish app:

```
// AppRoute.js
export default class AppRoute {
  constructor() {
    this.path = '/';
    this.indexRoute = new GoalsRoute();
  }
  getComponent(location, cb) {
    cb(null, AppContainer);
  }
}

// GoalsRoute.js
export default class GoalsRoute {
  constructor() {
    this.indexRoute = new MyGoalsRoute();
  }
  getComponent(location, cb) {
    cb(null, GoalsContainer);
  }
}

// MyGoalsRoute.js
export default class MyGoalsRoute {
  getComponent(location, cb) {
    cb(null, MyGoalsContainer);
  }
}
```

But when I render the application tree the `children` prop of the `GoalsContainer` doesn't exist when I would have expected the `MyGoalsContainer` to be there.

Can two IndexRoutes not be nested in this fashion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Index routes are not meant to be nested like this - we stop as soon as we hit the first index route when we do route matching.

If you want to follow this pattern, instead nest the index route in a path-less route. In JSX, it would look like

```
<Route path="/">
  <Route component={Parent}>
    <IndexRoute component={Child} />
  </Route>
</Route>
```

For more details, see https://github.com/rackt/react-router/pull/2330, the PR that implemented support for this behavior.